# why not call back function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, callback

Here is the entire function to perform my parent the event (with json).

```
function message_action(){
    function tipsy(){
        $("div#box_message > div > div.slimScrollDiv > div > ul > li, div.messagePopup > div.nav > div.name > a, div.messagePopup > div.box > div.content > ul > li > div.message_avatar, div.messagePopup > div.box > div.content > ul > li.user > div.message_text").tipsy({
            html: true,
            gravity: 'e',
        });
        $("div.messagePopup > div.box > div.content > ul > li.guy > div.message_text").tipsy({
            html: true,
            gravity: 'w',
        });
    }
    tipsy();
    function sound(){
        if($("audio.sounds-notification").length != 0){
            $("audio.sounds-notification").remove();
            $.playSound_notification('../data/sounds/notification');
        }else {
            $.playSound_notification('../data/sounds/notification');
        }
    }
    function view(id){
        var div = $("div.messagePopup[data-id="+id+"]");
        div.mouseover(function(){
            if(div.hasClass('see') == false){
                $.post('../function/message',{view:id},function(){
                    div.addClass('see');
                });
            }
        });
    }
    function message(){
        $.post('../function/message',{message:'friend'},function(data){
            var ul = $("div#box_message > div#friend_message > div.slimScrollDiv > div.friend_box_content > ul");
            for(var i in data){
                rows = data[i];
                ul.append(getCode(rows.avatar_img, rows.fullname, rows.guy_id, rows.username));
                tipsy();
            }
            open();
            search();
        },'json');
        function search(){
            var input = $("div#box_right > div#box_message > div#option_message > div.search > input");
            input.keyup(function(){
                var keyword = input.val();
                if(keyword == ''){
                    $("div#box_right > div#box_message > div#search_message").slideUp('fast');
                    $("div#box_right > div#box_message > div#friend_message").slideDown('fast');
                }else {
                    $("div#box_right > div#box_message > div#search_message").slideDown('fast');
                    $("div#box_right > div#box_message > div#friend_message").slideUp('fast');
                    $.post('../function/message',{search:keyword},function(data){
                        console.log(data);
                        var ul = $("div#box_right > div#box_message > div#search_message > div.slimScrollDiv > div > ul");
                        ul.html('');
                        if(data != ''){
                            for(var i in data){
                                var rows = data[i];
                                var li = ul.children('li');
                                if(li.length == 0){
                                    ul.append(getCode(rows.avatar_img, rows.fullname, rows.guy_id, rows.username));
                                }else {
                                    li.after(getCode(rows.avatar_img, rows.fullname, rows.guy_id, rows.username));
                                }
                                open();
                            }
                        }else {
                            ul.html("<li class='note_nodata'><a>Không tìm thấy người này</a></li>");
                        }
                    },'json');
                }
            });
        }
        function getCode(avatar_img, fullname, guy_id, username){
            code = '<li data-id="'+guy_id+'" class="east" quick-title="@'+username+'"><div class="avatar"><a href="../wall/'+username+'" style="background-image: url('+avatar_img+');"></a></div><div class="name" style="border-color: transparent"><a>'+fullname+'</a></div></li>';
            return code;
        }
    }
    message();
    function open(){
        var li = $("div#box_message > div > div.slimScrollDiv > div > ul > li");
        li.click(function(){
            var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
            popup(id);
        });
    }
    function popup(id){
        var div = $("div.messagePopup[data-id='"+id+"']");
        if(div.length == 0){
            $.post('../function/message',{show:id},function(data){
                console.log(data);
                if(data.view == 'see'){
                    div.addClass('see');
                }
            },'json');
            code = '<div class="messagePopup" data-id="'+id+'"><div class="nav"><div class="name"><a>'+name+'</a></div><div class="button"><div class="close"><a></a></div></div></div><div class="box"><div class="content"><ul></ul></div><div class="type"><textarea type="text" placeholder="Viết tin nhắn"></textarea></div></div></div>';
            $("div#giccos").after(code);
            var div = $("div.messagePopup[data-id='"+id+"']");
            $("div.messagePopup[data-id='"+id+"'] > div.nav > div.name").append('<div id="loading" class="loading_data_w" style="width: 20px;display: inline-block;vertical-align: top;margin-top: 10px;margin-left: 6px;"><i></i></div>');
            div.addClass('new');
            var div_new = $("div.messagePopup[data-id='"+id+"'].new");
            div_new.message();
            getData(id,'','','','false');
            status(id,'',30000);
            load(id);
            check(id);
            post(id);
            view(id);
            div_new.removeClass('new');
        }
    }
    function newPopup(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $.post('../function/message',{check:''},function(data){
                console.log(data);
                for(var i in data){
                    var rows = data[i];
                    var id = rows.user_id;
                    var div = $("div.messagePopup");
                    if(id != null && div.length == 0){
                        popup(id);
                        sound();
                    }
                }
            },'json');
            newPopup();
        },'6000');
    }
    newPopup();
    function getData(id,type,message_id,timeout,notification){
        $.post('../function/message',{data:id,type:type,message_id:message_id},function(data){
            console.log(data);
            var popup = $("div.messagePopup[data-id='"+id+"']");
            var div = $("div.messagePopup[data-id='"+id+"'] > div.box > div.content");
            var ul = div.children('ul');
            for(var i in data){
                var rows = data[i];
                if(type == 'old'){
                    var ulHeight_old = ul.height();
                    ul.children('li[message-id="'+message_id+'"]').before(getCode(rows.avatar_img, rows.content, rows.message_id, rows.time, rows.user, ''));
                    ulHeight = ul.height();
                    div.scrollTop(ulHeight - ulHeight_old);
                }if(type == 'new'){
                    ul.append(getCode(rows.avatar_img, rows.content, rows.message_id, rows.time, rows.user, ' new'));
                    ulHeight = ul.height();
                    div.scrollTop(ulHeight);
                    ul.children('li.new').fadeOut(function(){
                        $(this).fadeIn().removeClass('new');
                    });
                    popup.removeClass('see');
                }else if(type == ''){
                    ul.append(getCode(rows.avatar_img, rows.content, rows.message_id, rows.time, rows.user, ''));
                    ulHeight = ul.height();
                    div.scrollTop(ulHeight);
                }
                tipsy();
                if(notification == 'true'){
                    sound();
                }
            }
            $("div.messagePopup[data-id='"+id+"'] > div.nav > div.name > div#loading").fadeOut(function(){
                $(this).remove();
            });
            if(type == 'old' && data == null){
                div.addClass('null');
                ul.children('div#loading').slideUp(function(){
                    $(this).remove();
                });
            }
        },'json');
        function getCode(avatar_img, content, message_id, time, user, type){
            if(user == 'user'){
                code = '<li class="user'+type+'" message-id="'+message_id+'"><div class="message_text east" quick-title="<span>Gửi lúc '+time+'</span>"><div>'+content+'</div><i></i></div></li>';
            }else if(user == 'guy'){
                code = '<li class="guy'+type+'" message-id="'+message_id+'"><div class="message_avatar"><img src="'+avatar_img+'" /></div><div class="message_text west" quick-title="<span>Gửi lúc '+time+'</span>"><i></i><div>'+content+'</div></div></li>';
            }
            return code;
        }
    }
    function status(id,color,timeout){
        $.post('../function/message',{status:id},function(data){
            console.log(data);
            var nav = $("div.messagePopup[data-id='"+id+"'] > div.nav");
            var name = nav.children('div.name').children('a');
            if(name.text() == ''){
                name.text(data.name);
            }
            if(data.status == 'offline'){
                nav.css('background-color','#75797C');
            }else {
                nav.css('background-color','#3A6A99');
            }
        },'json');
        if(timeout != ''){
            setTimeout(function(){
                status(id,color,timeout);
            },timeout);
        }
    }
    function load(id){
        var div = $("div.messagePopup[data-id='"+id+"'] > div.box > div.content");
        div.scroll(function(){
            if($(this).scrollTop() == 0 && div.hasClass('null') == false){
                var message_id = $("div.messagePopup[data-id='"+id+"'] > div.box > div.content > ul > li[message-id]:first").attr('message-id');
                var loading = $("div.messagePopup[data-id='"+id+"'] > div.box > div.content > ul > div.loading_data_b");
                if(loading.length == 0){
                    $('li[message-id="'+message_id+'"]').before('<div id="loading" class="loading_data_b" style="padding: 10px;"><i></i></div>');
                }
                getData(id,'old',message_id,'','false');
            }
        });
    }
    function check(id){
        setTimeout(function(){
            var div = $("div.messagePopup[data-id='"+id+"']");
            if(div.length != 0){
                var message_id = $("div.messagePopup[data-id='"+id+"'] > div.box > div.content > ul > li[message-id]:last").attr('message-id');
                getData(id,'new',message_id,'','true');
                check(id);
            }
        },'4000');
    }
    function post(id){
        var input = $("div.messagePopup[data-id='"+id+"'] > div.box > div.type > textarea");
        $(input).keypress(function(event){
            var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
            if(keycode == '13'){
                var input = $(this);
                var val = input.val();
                var message_id = $("div.messagePopup[data-id='"+id+"'] > div.box > div.content > ul > li[message-id]:last").attr('message-id');
                if(val != ''){
                    $.post('../function/message',{post:val,id:id,},function(data){
                        input.val('');
                        getData(id,'new',message_id,'','false');
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
message_action();
```

The whole thing works well as function newPopup() returns a value. At this point it will call the function popup() returns id. But the function is called in the function popup() is not implemented. Why?

Comment: Please create a http://jsfiddle.net version - there is no way I'm reading through all that code

Comment: @freefaller:all my code on it, it's not related to HTML and PHP or some other code, please review and help me.

Comment: Thanks all, i fixed it. :)
Wishing everyone a good day